# Define variables in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I am quite new to Oracle SQL Developer. It looks like a very simple thing, but it is driving me nuts.

```
DEFINE START_DATE = "to_date('03/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')";
DEFINE END_DATE = "to_date('01/06/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')";

SELECT  
    SOMETABLE.JOB_BASE_NUM,
    SOMETABLE.CUSTOMER_CODE
FROM
    SOMETABLE
WHERE              
    SOMETABLE.WORK_END_DATE>= &START_DATE
    AND SOMETABLE.WORK_END_DATE < &END_DATE;
```

It always ask me to Enter value for END_DATE:

[image]

Can someone help please? Thank you.

Edit:
I run this in SQL Developer:

[image]

Comment: Are you running all the Lines in the script as one batch or just SELECT?

Comment: One batch in SQL developer

Comment: By the way, Oracle supports the ANSI standard syntax for date literals, e.g. `date '2018-01-03'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon here:

```
DEFINE START_DATE = "to_date('03/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')"
DEFINE END_DATE = "to_date('01/06/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')"
```

The semicolon is separating your define variable from your sql.